# What do these CSS code snippets do?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've gotten help coding a CSS & HTML-only responsive menu, and am unsure what some of the CSS code means, these are the parts that I would like help with:

```css
#nav-expand:checked + .nav-side {
#nav-collapse + .main-base {
#nav-collapse:checked + .main-base {
#nav-collapse + .main-base > .overlay {
#nav-collapse:checked + .main-base > .overlay {
```

I have understood that `>` selects anything that is a direct child of an element, so I guess that `.main-base > .overlay` means that only the `.overlay` that is a child of `.main-base` will be affected when `#nav-collapse` is checked?
I'm pretty much a beginner so please keep explanations simple =)

edit: this is how the bare HTML looks:

```
<input type="radio" id="nav-expand" name="nav" class="invis" /> 
<nav class="nav-side">
<label for="nav-collapse" class="close">
&times;
</label>
<label for="nav-expand" class="btn-label">
&#9776;
</label>
<ul class="menu-list">
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
</ul>
<input type="radio" id="nav-collapse" name="nav" checked="checked"        class="invis" />
<main class="main-base">
<label for="nav-collapse" class="overlay"></label>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have understood that `>` selects anything that is a direct child of an element, so I guess that `.main-base > .overlay` means that only the `.overlay` that is a child of `.main-base` will be affected when `#nav-collapse` is checked?

Yes; and only when `.main-base` directly follows `#nav-collapse` (which is what the `+` means), as in

```
<input id="nav-collapse" type="checkbox" checked>
<div class="main-base">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

The `.overlay` in these examples won't be affected:

```
<input id="nav-collapse" type="checkbox" checked>
<div class="main-base">
  <div>
    <div class="overlay"></div> <!-- Not a child of .main-base -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<p><input id="nav-collapse" type="checkbox" checked></p>
<div class="main-base"> <!-- Not an immediate sibling of #nav-collapse, but of the p -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

```
<input id="nav-collapse" type="checkbox" checked>
<h1></h1>
<div class="main-base"> <!-- Not an immediate sibling of #nav-collapse, but of the h1 -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, so with this html, if you were to comment/explain what that css means, how would you do that?

    <input type="radio" id="nav-expand" name="nav" class="invis" /> 

    <nav class="nav-side">

    <label for="nav-collapse" class="close">
    &times;
    </label>

    <label for="nav-expand" class="btn-label">
    &#9776;
   </label>

   <ul class="menu-list">
   <li> </li>
   <li> </li>
   <li> </li>
   </ul>

   <input type="radio" id="nav-collapse" name="nav"      checked="checked" class="invis" />

   <main class="main-base">

   <label for="nav-collapse" class="overlay"></label>

Comment: @Viveka: I suggest adding that HTML to your question as comments don't support code blocks making them hard to read.

Comment: @Viveka: The explanation is pretty much the same as how you have explained it with my addition. So, ".overlay that is a child of .main-base that directly follows #nav-collapse when it is checked."

Comment: Ok, so the last two lines of the css are only relevant to the last three lines of the html? and when they are in that specific order, it looks a specific way? @BoltClock

Comment: @Viveka: Yes, exactly.

Comment: aah, ok, I think I got it now, thank you! and thank you @AlexChar

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #nav-expand:checked + .nav-side
> ```

Selects element with class `.nav-side` which previous sibling element(input type checkbox) is checked with id `nav-expand`

```css
#nav-expand:checked + .nav-side {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-expand" checked />
<div class="nav-side">
  test
</div>
```

> ```
> #nav-collapse + .main-base
> ```

Select element with class `.main-base` when previous sibling element has id `#nav-collapse`:

```css
#main-base + .main-base {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-base"></div>
<div class="main-base">test</div>
```

> ```
> #nav-collapse:checked + .main-base
> ```

Same with first example.

> ```
> #nav-collapse + .main-base > .overlay
> ```

Select direct child element with class `.overlay` which parent element has class `.main-base` which previous sibling has id `#nav-collapse`:

```css
#nav-collapse + .main-base > .overlay {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-collapse"></div>
<div class="main-base">
  <div class="overlay">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#nav-collapse:checked + .main-base > .overlay
```

Same with previous but this time element with id `#nav-collapse` is input with type `checkbox` and is checked.

```css
#nav-collapse:checked + .main-base > .overlay {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-collapse" checked />
<div class="main-base">
  <div class="overlay">
    test
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      not this
    </div>
    not this
  </div>
</div>
```